# Are there resources for "derivations"?

Tags: reference-request, online-resources

Are there sites or resources that contain step-by-step derivations of mathematical expressions or concepts (e.g. the convolution integral) like it's done here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Visual_explanation?

Don't suggest [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org) since it's slightly different.

Comment: I haven't used it before, but [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) Pro is supposed to show and explain the steps used to solve a mathematical problem (including derivatives). Also, just by googling "Step by step derivative calculator", I quickly found [this](http://www.derivative-calculator.net/).

Comment: Visual explanations don't always exist.

Comment: @CaptainObvious Not looking for step-by-step solutions, rather step-by-step explanations of mathematical expressions or concepts.

Comment: Sorry, misread the above title as derivatives for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

There is no database of such things. In general, visual motivations for proofs and concepts are useful, but can be very hard to clearly create. If you have a specific example in mind, I would recommend making a post asking for a visual explanation of the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is no database of such things as said by stella but there are always different resources or sites (not a single one) certainly for the different elementary concepts and they can explain or visualize things.

Also there are many videos from different universities or institutions which provide a good explanation of concepts which can be reffered.

If you don't find such a site or resource which could help you then you ask questions here.